# Collision-proof hash-like identificator

Tags: hash, saas, url-shortener

I need to generate a 6 chars length (letters and digits) id to identify SaaS workspace (unique per user). Of course I could just go with numbers, but it shouldn't provide any clear vision about the real workspace number (for the end user).

So even for id 1 it should be 6 chars length and something like `fX8gz6` and fully decodable to `1` or `000001` or something that i can parse to real workspace id. And of course it have to be collision-proof.

What would be the best approach for that?

Comment: 6 chars is a hard limit or you can be a flexible like 8 chars or 10 chars?

Comment: @inquisitive sorry for my late answer, and yes: 6 was just an example, 8 chars are totally fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something similar to what Amazon uses for its cloud assets, but it uses 8 chars. Actually 8 chars is suitable as it is the output range after Base64 encoding of 6 binary bytes.

Assuming you have the flexibility to use 8 characters. In original question you said 6 chars, but again assuming. Here is a possible scheme:

1. Number your assets in `Unsigned Int32`, possibly auto-increment fashion. call it `real-id`. Use this real-id for all your internal purposes.
2. When you need to display it, follow something like this:
3. Convert your integer to 4 binary Bytes. Every language has library to extract the bytes out of integers and vice versa. Call it `real-id-bytes`
4. take a two byte random number. Again you can use libraries to generate an exact 16 bit random number. You can use cryptographic random number generators for better result, or the plain `rand` is just fine. Call it `rand-bytes`
5. Obtain 6 byte **`display-id-bytes`**`= array-concat(rand-bytes, real-id-bytes)`
6. Obtain **`display-id`**`= Base64(display-id-bytes)`. This is exactly 8 chars long and has a mix of lowercase, uppercase and digits.

Now you have a seemingly random 8 character `display-id` which can be mapped to the `real-id`. To convert back:

1. Take the 8 character `display-id`
2. **`display-id-bytes`**`= Base64Decode(display-id)`
3. **`real-id-bytes`**`= Discard-the-2-random-bytes-from(display-id-bytes)`
4. **`real-id`**`= fromBytesToInt32(real-id-bytes)`

Simple. Now if you really cannot go for 8-char display-id then you have to develop some custom base-64 like algo. Also you might restrict yourself to only 1 random bytes. Also note that This is just an encoding scheme, NOT a encryption scheme. So anyone having the knowledge of your scheme can effectively break/decode the ID. You need to decide whether that is acceptable or not. If not then I guess you have to do some form of encryption. Whatever that is, surely 6-chars will be far insufficient.

Comment: there is no need for any encryption, it's just to make user unaware of the real id number, in case when somebody tries guessing or hacking any existing id there will be 404 (if no privileges for this certain workspace)

Comment: fine, then a scheme like this should work for you. The steps like extracting-bytes, random-number, base64 etc are very easy in dot-net and java with built in libraries. you never said which language you are using.

Comment: also, as far i understand these 2-random-bytes have to allways be two first bytes of the display-id-bytes, so when doing discard-2-random-bytes i just remove two first bytes, and that's it?

Comment: actually this is a choice. you might make it first-two or last-two or middle-two. but yes you have to keep that position constant for every one. then you know which two bytes to discard. Interestingly, these bytes need not be all random. these can be derived from the real-id itself, like sum of all the digits. credit cards do this with their numbers.

Comment: Ok, got it :) And yes i hadn't said what i'm using. Actually i'm using Ruby, but my question was language-agnostic i think. You can, however, update your answer with some code examples for completeness if you want, but i will accept your answer anyway as that's exactly what i needed, thanks a lot :)